# How to get value from slider bar in specific php structure

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

im nearly at the end of my form coding yet i'm stuck in the form proces phase , my problem is i dont get value from my sliders  here my slider code :

```
<section>
     <label class="label">
         Simple <p style="float:right">Complex (<span  id="slider1-value">0</span</p>
      </label>   
      <div id="slider1" name="slider1"></div>
      <input type='hidden' name='slider1-value'  />
</section>

  <section>
     <label class="label">
         Playful <p style="float:right">Serious(<span  id="slider2-value">0</span>)</p></label> 
      <div id="slider2" name="slider2"></div>
      <input type="hidden"  name="slider2-value" />
    </section>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function()
    {
        // Regular slider
        $('#slider1').slider({
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        values: [50],
        slide: function(event, ui)
        {
            $('#slider1-value').text(ui.value);
        }
    });

    $('#slider2').slider({
        min: 0,
        max: 100,             
        values: [50],
        slide: function(event, ui)
        {
            $('#slider2-value').text(ui.value);
        }
    });
```

and finally php:

```
<?php
    if( isset($_POST['name']) )
    {
        $to = 'mylogo@gmail.com';
        $subject = 'NEWLOGO CLIENT FORM';
        $headers = 'From: ' . $_POST['email'] . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $_POST['email'];    

        $message = 'Name: ' . $_POST['name'] . "\n" .
                   'Surname: ' . $_POST['surname'] . "\n" .
                   'E-mail: ' . $_POST['email'] . "\n" .
                   'Phone: ' . $_POST['phone']. "\n" .
                   'Simple vs Complex : ' . $_POST['slider1-value']. "\n";                   

        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);    
        if( $_POST['copy'] == 'on' )
        {
            mail($_POST['email'], $subject, $message, $headers);
        }
    }

?>
```

When on action the id `#slider1-value'` shows me the value right in the form but when submitted i don't get any value, i'm not very familiar with php what should i do ? do i need some javascript or jquery help ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Once you will resolve your prob, you should check all your data input and properly securize them. This is VERY IMPORTANT : *NEVER TRUST USER INPUT* (wich means you have to check in your process even if you checked in javascript before sending etc etc ...) !

Comment: Btw you put `$_POST['slider1-value']`, you never ask for slider2-value ? That's normal then that you don't get slider2-value in this case ^^ Except this and security holes, i don't realy see probs ...

Comment: if you mean validating all the sectors all are validated before submitting , i just wrote slider2 as a example cuz i have 5 of them i'm a beginner in php and this is my first processing code besides thank you for your advices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are putting the slider value into the contents of a `span`. Something a `form` knows nothing of. This is why you are getting an empty value on the server.

This makes complete sense in terms of UI, but you need to assign the slider value to the actual form input you have already made named `slider1-value`

Your jQuery will look something like this...

```
$('input[name="slider1-value"]').val(ui.value);
```

Repeat for slider 2.

Comment: Finally this worked thank you man you made my day , after removing the <span> tags and changing the jquery code as you said it worked , Regards

Answer (score 1):

When you set the data into your 2 sliders you set the `.text` property and not the `.value` property of the input element. Therefore that fields does not actually have a value.

Also you have used the id `slider-value2` twice, thats not legal.

Try this :

The HTML markup corrected:

```
<section>
     <label class="label">
         Simple <p style="float:right">Complex (<span  id="slider1-value">0</span</p>
      </label>   
      <div id="slider1" name="slider1"></div>
      <input type='hidden' id='slider1-actual-value' name='slider1-actual-value'  />
</section>

<section>
     <label class="label">
         Playful <p style="float:right">Serious(<span  id="slider2-value">0</span>)</p></label> 
      <div id="slider2" name="slider2"></div>
      <input type="hidden" id="slider2-actual-value" name="slider2-actual-value" />
</section>
```

The javascript corrected:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function()
{
    // Regular slider
    $('#slider1').slider({
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    values: [50],
    slide: function(event, ui)
    {
        $('#slider1-value').text(ui.value);
        $('#slider1-actual-value').val(ui.value);
    }
});

$('#slider2').slider({
    min: 0,
    max: 100,             
    values: [50],
    slide: function(event, ui)
    {
        $('#slider2-value').text(ui.value);
        $('#slider2-actual-value').val(ui.value);
    }
});
```

Comment: Check out the HTML markup again. I don't think a form is going to send the value attribute of a span element by default.

Comment: @IanBrindley Actually `slider1_value` is a `<input type="hidden"...` but you are right about the `slider2-value` i will edit my answer to fix that anomily.

Comment: Check it out again. You'll notice that the OP is trying to update it's value by fetching the DOM element by an id... that input has no id.

Comment: @IanBrindley yup I did and corrected both I didnt expect that silly error.Fixed now I think? Thanks for the nudge.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the jquery:

Try using `$('#slider1-value').val(ui.value)` instead of `...text(ui.value)`